# Is there a way to add a hardware keyboard layout with F1, F2, F3... keys on the iPad Air?

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I'm using TinyTerm ITX on the iPad Air to access our ERP software in Wyse60 mode.  Some keys are not functioning properly, but for the most part usable.  On various Bluetooth keyboards, the Fn-F1, Fn-F2, Fn-F3... keys just won't work.  I tried the hardware keyboard layout "U.S. International - PC" with some success with slash commands, but not with the F1, F2, F3... keys.

I just ordered another vendor's BT Keyboard to see if this one is malfunctioning.

I know the iPad Air support F keys, because the onboard keyboard has "PC English with Fn Keys".  And it works fine (except Page Up and Page Down).

It would be nice to be able to program a new hardware keyboard.  Has anyone done this on the iPad Air?

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing "pc english with fn keys"?

Comment: In TinyTerm ITX, there is a keyboard icon on the upper right of the screen.  It shows various virtual keyboards, PC English, PC English with Fn Keys, etc.  Using the onscreen keyboard, all the F keys work great.  It's just the Bluetooth will not work by pressing Fn, then the F key.  Its almost like the Fn button isn't working, because it will increase or decrease the screen brightness instead of using F1 or F2.